# pandas groupby error for collection repeated values?

Tags: pandas, data-science

I am trying to gather all the repeated values and their count.

My Dataset:
[image]

In the above picture suppose fox appears 3 then `Fox 3` in that way I want. I tried to use group by but it shows me error of "Sum." something.

```
studios.groupby(a).value_counts().to_frame('count')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you just want to calculate count of duplicates in studio column ?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @tawab_shakeel That's what I want!

Comment: @anky_91 Thank you for advise I will look forward to it!

Comment: bdw `df['studio_count']=df.studio+' '+df.groupby('studio).studio.transform('size').astype(str)` seems to do your job